# mysql : grant all priviledges to one user on all tables/columns in one command

Tags: mysql

how could I grant all priviledges to one user on all tables/columns in one command ?

I'm trying some variants of this without success. I think I'm a little confused between several MySQL versions. I'm using MySQL 5.5.16 now... Intranet is the name of my database

```
use intranet
grant CREATE,INSERT,SELECT,DELETE,UPDATE on intranet.* to 'owl-user@host'
```

UPDATE : I'm afraid none of the below works for me at the moment. I tried this :

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE ON intranet.* TO 'owl-user'@'host';
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
mysql>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user exists and the host is correct (should be localhost most of times)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'; WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Don't forget to put BOTH the username AND the host part in quotes.
The database in MySQL is selected using `Use dbname` command.

So basically you want to run the following sequence:

```
use intranet;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'; WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Hi jsshah. When I try this, I receive `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''localhost; WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1`. MySQL version 5.6.17.

Answer (score 0):

`GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE , CREATE ON  intranet . * TO  'owl-user'@'host';` works fine here

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure enough that user given by you exists than try full query with clause "identified by 'password';